# Date type xAxis in Angular Highcharts is still allowing duplicate 'Date' values

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have implemented a chart using angular highcharts but i am encountering an issue which is related to duplicate x values. Attached is the screenshot for your reference. Please check below code as well

```
            let targetData = chartArray.filter(data => (data.zvalue === 'Target' || data.zvalue === 'Previsione' ));
            let providedData = chartArray.filter(data => (data.zvalue === 'Provided'));

            let allChartLabels = chartArray.map(label => label.xvalue);

            let allTargetData = targetData.map(data => data.yvalue);
            let allProvidedData = providedData.map(data => data.yvalue);

            this.dayChartOptions.title = {
                text: this.personalReportForm.value.name    
            }
            this.dayChartOptions.tooltip = {
                enabled:true,
                crosshairs:true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.series.name + '<br>'
                    + 'y: <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
                }
            }
            /////////// Date Type /////////////
            this.dayChartOptions.xAxis = {
                type: 'date',
                categories: allChartLabels,
            }
            this.dayChartOptions.yAxis.title = {
                text: 'Percent'
            }

            this.dayChartOptions.series[0] = {
                type: 'scatter',
                name: 'Target',
                data: allTargetData,
                marker: {
                    fillColor: '#1985ac'
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    color: '#1985ac',
                    // color: '#ffc107',
                },
            };
```

[image]

Please let me know how to get rid of these duplicate values, I have read highcharts documentation in detail but couldn't find this solution.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the content of the chartArray variable? Your categories have to be duplicated. Could you reproduce your issue in an online code editor like codesandbox, jsfiddle? Templates: https://codesandbox.io/s/543l0p0qq4, https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x1ydrjuk/

Comment: basically the data coming from API has duplicate dates but type 'date' should remove those duplicate values

Comment: 0: {zvalue: "Target", xvalue: "01/01/2019", yvalue: 98.5, description: null}
1: {zvalue: "Provided", xvalue: "01/01/2019", yvalue: 100, description: null}
2: {zvalue: "Target", xvalue: "02/01/2019", yvalue: 98.5, description: null}
3: {zvalue: "Provided", xvalue: "02/01/2019", yvalue: 100, description: null}
4: {zvalue: "Target", xvalue: "03/01/2019", yvalue: 98.5, description: null}
5: {zvalue: "Provided", xvalue: "03/01/2019", yvalue: 100, description: null}

This is the data from API

Answer (score 0):

To achieve it you have to split data into two separate series:

```js
var data = [{
  zvalue: "Target",
  xvalue: "01/01/2019",
  yvalue: 98.5,
  description: null
}, {
  zvalue: "Provided",
  xvalue: "01/01/2019",
  yvalue: 100,
  description: null
}, {
  zvalue: "Target",
  xvalue: "02/01/2019",
  yvalue: 98.5,
  description: null
}, {
  zvalue: "Provided",
  xvalue: "02/01/2019",
  yvalue: 100,
  description: null
}, {
  zvalue: "Target",
  xvalue: "03/01/2019",
  yvalue: 98.5,
  description: null
}, {
  zvalue: "Provided",
  xvalue: "03/01/2019",
  yvalue: 100,
  description: null
}];

var mappedData = data.map(elem => ({
  name: elem.zvalue,
  x: Date.parse(elem.xvalue),
  y: elem.yvalue
}));

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter'
  },
  xAxis: {
    tickPositioner: function() {
     return mappedData
       .filter(elem => elem.name === 'Provided')
        .map(elem => elem.x);
    },
    labels: {
     formatter: function () {
       return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e/%b/%y', this.value);
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      var point = this.point,
        series = this.series,
        header =
         '<span style="color:' +
         point.color +
         '">\u25CF</span>' +
          '<span style="font-size: 10px"> ' +
          point.name +
          '</span><br/>',
        body =
         'x: <b>' +
         Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', point.x) +
         '</b><br/>' +
          'y: <b>' +
          point.y +
          '</b>';

      return header + body;
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Provided',
    data: mappedData.filter(elem => elem.name === 'Provided')
  }, {
    name: 'Target',
    marker: {
      fillColor: '#1985ac'
    },
    data: mappedData.filter(elem => elem.name === 'Target')
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ft7ejvuh/1/